# PhantomJs: Can I access relative assets from a page with dynamically set content?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, relative-path

Given the following file structure:

```
project-folder
 |- images/
 |  |- foo.png
 |
 |- script.js
```

And something like the following Phantom script:

```
var page1 = require("webpage").create(),
  page2 = require("webpage").create();

page1.content = "<img src='images/foo.png'/>";
page2.content = "<img src='file:///path/to/project-folder/images/foo.png'/>";

// give the images some time to load
setTimeout(function () {
  page1.render("pdf1.pdf");
  page2.render("pdf2.pdf");
  phantom.exit();
}, 10);
```

After running this, `foo.png` displays correctly in `pdf2.pdf` but not in `pdf1.pdf`.

I need to render a large HTML file that has a number of images with relative paths, as in page1.

While it's possible to go through the markup using some kind of crazy regex and change all the image src attributes manually to the script's working folder before setting the content, I'd rather avoid it.

Is there some other option I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [an issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10610) about this on GitHub. It seems that there is no option to pass the base directory to PhantomJS. However, you can set the base url with the [HTML base tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

Comment: Excellent answer, didn't know about the base tag. This works very well with the test case above but when I tried it on my large HTML file, well, all text stopped rendering. Seems like a bug with PhantomJS.

Comment: Oops, correction, it was an issue with some @font-face rules with a relative path. Which I guess shows how well the base tag solution works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks, it helped me too